# Load images from "HTTPS" type of url and display in UIImageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, uiimageview, xcode6

I am developing an iOS app in which I receive "HTTPS" URLs from server for images. I am now unable to load images from those URLs. I have tried several frameworks like AFNetworking, SDImageView, etc. But none of them are able to load image from these type of URLs.

Update:

Code sample

```
[cell.imgVwPhoto setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        [UIView transitionWithView:cell.imgVwPhoto
        duration:0.2
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
        animations:^{
            cell.imgVwPhoto.image = image;
        }
        completion:NULL];
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }];
```

Here URL is of HTTPS type.
So, this is not working.

Any help would be much thankful.

Comment: show some code, how do you load those images? Did you tried to load from another https resource? What's the error that occurs when loading those images, if any?

Comment: Would you please share your complete image url

Comment: Sorry i cant share it

Comment: Are you sure you having an image on this url? No html as a result o hotlinking protection?

Comment: What error are you getting? Maybe change your NSLog to `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Issue resolved by modifying some parameters into the framework for webservice calling created by me.
All those changes were as per the server which I was calling to.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share what changed you made?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL"];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *aImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurl/mypic.jpg"]];
UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
```

hope it helps.

Comment: its not working, i have already tried this.
Error Shown for your code : NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Comment: can I see your code and url your passing to image view?

Comment: I have tried your code and URL is any general URL but of HTTPS type.

Comment: Check your url your not getting data in response to your url.

Comment: I can open the image in browser from that URL but not in iOS code.
So, there is no problem with URL.